# переход по url Django, в url адрес не меняется

Tags: python, django

```py
urls.py
urlpatterns = [
                  path('', views.auth, name='auth'),  # Страница входа.
                  path('viewBirds.html/', views.viewBirds, name='viewBirds'),  # Представление птиц.
                  path('creatBirds.html/', views.creatBirds, name='creatBirds'),  # Создание птиц.
                  path('creatUser.html/', views.rgstrUser, name='rgstrUser'),  # Создание пользователя.
                  path('viewUser.html/', views.viewUser, name='viewUser'),  # Просмотренные птицы.
              ] + static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

```py
views.py
def auth(request):
    """Процесс аутентификации пользователя."""
    if request.method == 'POST':
        login = request.POST.get("login")
        password = request.POST.get("password")
        pswHash = sha256(password.encode('utf-8')).hexdigest()
        user = User.objects.filter(login=login, password=pswHash)

        if user:  # Если логин и пароль существуют, то переходим на основную форму, это процесс авторизации.
            return render(request, 'viewBirds.html/', {"login": login})
        elif login is not None:
            ErorrMessage = "Неправильный логин или пароль."
            return render(request, 'auth.html/', {"Error": ErorrMessage})

    return render(request, 'auth.html/')
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Title</title>
</head>
<body>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://pyscript.net/alpha/pyscript.css" />
<form method="post" action="{% url 'auth' %}"> {% csrf_token %}
    <style>
            .center {
                text-align: center;
                 }
            .btn {
                text-align: center
                display: inline-block; /* Строчно-блочный элемент */
                background: #8C959D; /* Серый цвет фона */
                color: #fff; /* Белый цвет текста */
                padding: 1rem 1.5rem; /* Поля вокруг текста */
                text-decoration: none; /* Убираем подчёркивание */
                border-radius: 3px; /* Скругляем уголки */
                text-align: center;
                }
    </style>
    <div class="center">
    <h3 style="center">Вход</h3>
        <font color="red" size="4" >
            <td>{{ Error }}</td>
        </font>
        <br>
            <input name="login" maxlength="80" minlength="1" type="text" placeholder="Логин" required />
        <br>
        <br>
        <div class="center">
          <input name="password" maxlength="80" minlength="3" type="password"   placeholder="Пароль" required />
        </div>
        <br>
        <input type="submit" value="Авторизация" class="btn"/>
        <br>
        <br>
        <a href="/creatUser.html/">
            <button name="registr" type="button" class="btn"/> Регистрация </button>
        </a>
    </div>

</form>
</body>
</html>
```

[image: после нажатие кнопки url не изменился]

Comment: переходит на другую страницу но на ней выводится информация, а url прежний

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Используйте редирект:

```
from django.shortcuts import redirect 

def auth(request):
"""Процесс аутентификации пользователя."""
if request.method == 'POST':
    login = request.POST.get("login")
    password = request.POST.get("password")
    pswHash = sha256(password.encode('utf-8')).hexdigest()
    user = User.objects.filter(login=login, password=pswHash)

    if user:  # Если логин и пароль существуют, то переходим на основную форму, это процесс авторизации.
        return redirect('viewBirds')
    elif login is not None:
        ErorrMessage = "Неправильный логин или пароль."
        return render(request, 'auth.html/', {"Error": ErorrMessage})

return render(request, 'auth.html/')
```

Comment: а login через него тоже можно отправить?

Comment: функция redirect позволяет передавать дополнительные параметры во view, но я бы передал логин в html шаблон из самой функции viewBirds

Comment: ок, спасибо!!!!